# groovy returning different node count

Tags: groovy, soapui

I am trying to get the count of result nodes in soapUI using groovy and the below code gave me the correct count

```
def groovyUtils = new com.eviware.soapui.support.GroovyUtils(context)
def holder = groovyUtils.getXmlHolder("StepName#ResponseAsXml")

def cnt = holder["count(//Results/ResultSet/Row)"]
```

but when i tried the below i got a count of 1. How are the two different?

```
def cnt = holder["count('//Results/ResultSet/Row')"]
```

Comment: In the second one, you are passing a String to `count`.  The first passes a path which I guess gets evaluated into a list of nodes. Though I've never used SoapUI

Comment: @tim_yates you should make that an answer

Comment: @tim_yates aren't xpath's also sent as strings something like this...

   reader.getNodeValues( "//ns1:node" )

Comment: `count()` in SoapUI takes an Xpath to generate the list which @tim_yates has pointed. Conversely, if a string  is passed to count would not evaluate the list. Keep [this](http://www.soapui.org/Scripting-Properties/tips-a-tricks.html#3-2-count-nodes) handy and refer [this](http://learnsoapui.wordpress.com/tag/count-in-xpath/) for more.

Comment: As I said, I don't use SoapUI, but I guess it's calling `holder.get( "count('//Results/ResultSet/Row')" )` and it's evaluating the path somehow into a String

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Though I've never used SoapUI, in the second one, you are passing a String (wrapped in `'...'`) to `count`.

The first passes a path which I guess gets evaluated into a list of nodes.

All the [examples I can find](http://www.soapui.org/Scripting-Properties/tips-a-tricks.html#3-2-count-nodes) do not wrap the path in a String, so my guess is the first example is the way to do it ;-)

**EDIT**
Refer [Tips and Tricks](http://www.soapui.org/Scripting-Properties/tips-a-tricks.html#1-1-get-and-set-properties) for most of the SoapUI and Groovy related questions. And [count in xpath](http://learnsoapui.wordpress.com/tag/count-in-xpath/).

Comment: Updated with some info, which I see many a times being asked with SoapUI. I am using your brand name Tim. ;)